# Tkinter を使ったデータフレームのグラフ表示で、ボタンを押してもグラフが更新されない

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

tkinterを使って、エクセルから作成したデータフレームをグラフとして表示させようとしています。しかし、”グラフ”・”グラフを更新”どちらのボタンを押しても、グラフが更新されないです。

```
import tkinter as tk
import csv
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1500x800")
root.title(u"Zero point treatment")
root.resizable(False,False)
#windowの設定

load = tk.Frame(root,width=500,height=500,borderwidth=1,relief='solid')
HSM = tk.Frame(root,width=500,height=500,borderwidth=1,relief='solid')
modulus = tk.Frame(root,width=500,height=500,borderwidth=1,relief='solid')
monitor = tk.Frame(root,width=500,height=300,borderwidth=1,relief='solid')
button = tk.Frame(root,width=500,height=300,borderwidth=1,relief='solid',cursor='hand2')
enter = tk.Frame(root,width=500,height=300,borderwidth=1,relief='solid')
#frameの定義

load.propagate(False)
HSM.propagate(False)
modulus.propagate(False)
monitor.propagate(False)
button.propagate(False)
enter.propagate(False)
#frameのサイズを固定

load.grid(row=0,column=0)
HSM.grid(row=0,column=1)
modulus.grid(row=0,column=2)
monitor.grid(row=1,column=2)
button.grid(row=1,column=0)
enter.grid(row=1,column=1)
#frameを配置

#＿＿＿＿＿＿＿約束の地　変数宣言＿＿＿＿＿＿＿
mini = 200
max = 500
#HSMどの範囲で補正するか初期設定。mini~max(nm)
x = []
y_load = []
y_HSM = []
y_mod = []
test_num = 2

#----------------------関数を定義---------------------

#-------------------------------graph関数はデータフレームからグラフを作る関数-----------------------------------
def graph_load():
    fig_l = plt.Figure()
    instance = fig_l.subplots()
    instance.plot(x,y_load)
    instance.set_xlabel("Depth(nm)")
    instance.set_ylabel("load(mN)")
    instance.set_ylim(-10,300)
    return fig_l

def graph_HSM():
    fig_H = plt.Figure()
    instance = fig_H.subplots()
    instance.plot(x,y_HSM)
    instance.set_xlabel("Depth(nm)")
    instance.set_ylabel("HSM(N/m)")
    instance.set_ylim(-10,3000000)
    return fig_H

def graph_mod():
    fig_mod = plt.Figure()
    instance = fig_mod.subplots()
    instance.plot(x,y_mod)
    instance.set_xlabel("Depth(nm)")
    instance.set_ylabel("modulus(GPa)")
    instance.set_ylim(-10,300)
    return fig_mod

def graph_load2():
    fig = plt.Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph_load(),master=load)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    ax.plot(x,y_load)
    ax.set_xlabel("Depth(nm)")
    ax.set_ylabel("load(mN)")
    ax.set_ylim(-10,300)
    canvas.draw()


#------------------------------------canvas関数はキャンバスを作り、グラフを置く関数----------------------------------------
def canvas_load():
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph_load(),master=load)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas.draw()
    return canvas_load

def canvas_HSM():
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph_HSM(),master=HSM)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas.draw()
    return canvas_HSM

def canvas_mod():
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph_mod(),master=modulus)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas.draw()
    return canvas_mod


#ボタンをクリックした時の挙動を設定する

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    title = "ゼロ点補正するエクセルファイルを選択",
    filetypes = [ ("Excelブック", ".xls") ], # ファイルフィルタ
    initialdir = "./" # 自分自身のディレクトリ
    )

#--------------------------データフレームを作成-------------------------------
df_load = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name='Test {:03}'.format(test_num),usecols=[1,2],skiprows=[0,1])
df_HSM = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name='Test {:03}'.format(test_num),usecols=[1,4],skiprows=[0,1])
df_mod = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name='Test {:03}'.format(test_num),usecols=[1,6],skiprows=[0,1])
#データフレームを作成

for line in range(1,1000):
    x.append(df_load.iat[line,0])
    y_load.append(df_load.iat[line,1])
    y_HSM.append(df_HSM.iat[line,1])
    y_mod.append(df_mod.iat[line,1])
    if df_load.iat[line,0] is None:
        break
#値があるだけエクセルからデータを読み込みアレイに変換

button_canvas = tk.Button(enter,text=u'グラフ',command=lambda:[graph_load(),graph_HSM(),graph_mod(),canvas_load(),canvas_HSM(),canvas_mod()])
button_canvas.pack()


button_canvas2 = tk.Button(enter,text=u'グラフ更新',command=lambda:[graph_load2()])
button_canvas2.pack()


root.mainloop()
#画面を表示
```

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[tkinterに表示したmatplotlibのグラフを更新する方法](https://torimakujoukyou.com/tkinter%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9Fmatplotlib%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/), [PythonでGUIグラフ操作アプリを作ってみる【Tkinter初心者】](https://mizorandum.com/tkinter-graph-app/), [Tkinterにmatplotlibグラフを埋め込み自由にグラフ配置](https://tomosoft.jp/design/?p=44161), [Tkinterにmatplotlibグラフを埋め込む](https://qiita.com/kotai2003/items/45953b4d037a62b2042c)

Comment: ちなみに他の人が問題を把握・再現・調査するためにテストデータも(件数が多ければ最小限に絞って)提示してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考にExcelのスクリーンショットではなく、CSVに変換したものをテキストで。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: 回答者は質問者さんの作業を肩代わりするわけではないので、そこもお忘れなく。

Comment: kuniｆさん
確かにテストデータや短いサンプルコードを提示することは重要です。
このコードは大きく書き直す必要ができたので、次回以降の質問ではその点に留意したいと思います。